# How do I connect to the router beyond mine?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Trying to learn about networking. I'm not 100% sure I'm asking the right question. I'm playing with nmap and similar tools to explore my own network. Fun. I want to jump one network up.

The way my home network is setup, my first router has another router plugged into it. Almost all the hosts are connected to the second router. I could do scans and play around on this network, but I can't figure out how to get onto the outer network without connecting my computer directly to it.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: How do you connect to the first router? By IP address? If so, your other should also have a (different) IP address that you can connect to.

Comment: Ya. I do it by IP. I can get to both routers' pages, through the browser, but I don't know how to scan that network for other devices.

Comment: How are you doing the scans you can do? What command?

Comment: well, generally you would set your target to the outter routers IP range. if the inner were 192.168.1.0 and the outter 192.168.0.0, you would simply put `192.168.0.0/24`. see here for details on specifying your target: https://nmap.org/book/man-target-specification.html Note that target is not an option, so anything on the command without a leading `-` is part of the target spec, so the command could be `nmap -A -T4 192.168.0.0/24`.

Comment: You can do this.  But expect this to be more complicated than you expect.  Often traffic may go from your computer to the internal/LAN port on your first router (e.g. 192.168.1.1), which routes traffic to the external/WAN port of the first router (e.g. 192.168.0.2), and then the second router sends traffic to desired device.  But when that device replies, the second router doesn't know to route 192.168.1.x to the first router, so traffic goes to the default gateway/Internet.  No replies.  The best solution is usually to set up proper routing, which may take a bit of time to learn how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your first router is connected to a WAN, and one of its output ports connects to the WAN port of a second router; your network devices then connect to the ports on the second router. Try disabling DHCP on the on the second router. The first router's DHCP function should ignore the second router and assign IP(s) to your network devices. If the second router has wireless functionality and the first does not, then the second router will perform those functions as it normally would as if it were the sole router.